# viewstate disappears on response.redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net, viewstate

On my asp.net c# page I have two text boxes(start and end dates) with ajax CalendarExtenders. The user selects a start date and then an end date. On selecting the end date, I bind my grid as shown below;

```
 protected void calEndDate_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BindGrid();
    }
```

In the grid I have a command button with the following code

```
 protected void gvAllRoomStatus_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {    
        if (e.CommandName == "Manage")
        {    
            GridViewRow row = gvAllRoomStatus.Rows[Convert.ToInt16(e.CommandArgument)];    
            int BookingID = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[1].Text);              

            DataClassesDataContext context = new DataClassesDataContext();
                Session["BookingID"] = BookingID;
                Response.Redirect("CheckIn.aspx");
        }
    }
```

When the user goes to that page and clicks the back button all the selected dates and the gridview data disappears. Any ideas why the viewstate is disappearing?

Answer (score 10):

`ViewState` belongs to the current `Page`.

Have a look: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37753/Access-ViewState-Across-Pages

> Yes, we can access the viewstate variables across pages. This is only
>   possible if Cross Page Posting or Server.transfer is used to redirect
>   the user to other page. **If Response.redirect is used, then ViewState
>   cannot be accessed across pages**.

So you could use `Server.Transfer` instead or use the `Session`.

Comment: server.transfer won't work either. May be I have updatepanels around my grid. Please have a look at the markup

Comment: Beside that, I think that when you submit a page, and then you go back most browsers keep what you have type on it (or I am wrong ?). I think that he make some other mistake and is not keep by browser, eg the multiple postbacks maybe is a reason. Also I do not see here how is use the ViewState.

Comment: @user1050179: You might want to have a look here: [Enable Back button support in ASP.NET AJAX web sites](http://geekswithblogs.net/frankw/archive/2008/10/29/enable-back-button-support-in-asp.net-ajax-web-sites.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Viewstate to look at it in a very simplified way is to see it as a carbon copy or cache of the last state of the page you are currently on. Therefore doing a redirect to any page, even the same page itself, is essentially a fresh start. The viewstate no longer applies as for all intent and purpose, you are on a new page.

As Tim suggests in his post, either store the required data as a session variable or use a server.transfer.

Take a look here for a nice overview of viewstate:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37753/Access-ViewState-Across-Pages

Comment: I can't add my markup here in the comment. This is strange or I need to add the markup differently

Comment: You should add it to your original post and mark it as being update, so that everyone can see how your question evolves.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the issue you have is because you make auto post backs with `calEndDate_TextChanged` using Ajax.

After your submit, when you press the back button the browser can not remember neither can save what you have change with all that auto post data with Ajax calls, and you lose them.

For me remove the Text Change auto post back, remove the Ajax because you do not needed and make a regular full post back when the user submit their data.

Then when you make back with the browser, browser load the previous state and most of the browsers remember what and all the input of the user. Also on that back the viewstate is the same as previous because did not have change from the Ajax.